# Identifying the jar file association on Task Manager

Tags: jar, taskmanager, javaw

I have a server which runs multiple jar file at the same time as of now.

Currently we just make a bat file, call the java -jar xxxx.jar program, and the window is pop-ed up on the screen so we know which to terminate when we'd like to turn one of them off.

But as we progress we prefer those program to run at the background hence we'd prefer to use javaw -jar xxxx.jar instead.

However when we open up the task manager all it shows is many javaw.exe processes, without telling us which jar file its associated to.

Is there any parameter we can specify when we start javaw, so there's some indication on task manager's process list?

Comment: In alternative, you can view "command line" column in task manager under processes, obtaining the jar absolute path and name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an official product named [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/tr-tr/en-en/sysinternals/bb896653) that can do what you want.